# Working as a replacement and want to quit

Tags: leave, replacement

As mentioned in title, I am working as a substitute for a person who went on a maternity leave. It will be now 9 Months for me to work here. The colleague of mine will return in 7-8 Months. 
I want to quit here and go work somewhere else, but I have fear from the reaction of my current boss. She took me, and expects me to work here till the colleague returns. If I leave, then she will need to find someone else, and teach him once again what she taught me, and so on. 
Also, what makes things worse is that they want to keep me, at least my boss told ME so. She will do her best, and have said that in front of the CEO

Comment: Hi and welcome in The Workplace. **[Questions require a goal that we can address.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)**  Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, see [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696).

Comment: If you have a better opportunity, leave. If the company didn't need you anymore, they'd let you go so fast your head would spin. Always keep your own interests in mind.

Comment: @user111583 welcome to the site.  As your question is currently worded it appears to be off topic.  Please consider editing your question to make it more clear what you are asking for help with.

Comment: Hi @user111583. If you edit a goal into this question, then I'll vote to reopen it. It looks like something we can help with, but we need to understand what outcome you're looking for, not just the situation you're in.

Answer (score 9):

**What you're describing is pretty much every job** (if you omit the Maternity Leave part.)

Seriously, the progression for pretty much every job is:

1. Previous person doing the job leaves (they quit, they're fired, they're promoted, whatever.)
2. New person is hired to do the job.
3. New person is trained by someone else on how to do the job.
4. New person does the job.
5. ... until that that person leaves the job, looping back to Step 1 with someone else.

You shouldn't stay on a job because "Then my boss will have to train my replacement!"  That happens pretty much every time anyone quits a job.  You shouldn't stay on a job because "The boss said they want to keep me!"  Bosses will almost always say that (replacing people can be a lot of work.)

**Instead, you should ask: Are You Happy There?  If you're happy, gaining skills and learning how to be a good employee?  Then stay.  If you're not happy there, not going skills or learning much - then find another job and then leave.**

Comment: insert Morgan Freeman "He's right, you know", meme.   +1